# Magento devbox not install

Tags: magento, docker, windows-10, magento2

I install magento devbox based on docker on windows10pro. And get error

> ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: invalid bind
>   mount spec
>   "C:\magedevbox\shared\logs\php-fpm:/var/log/php-fpm:rw": invalid
>   volume specification:
>   'C:\magedevbox\shared\logs\php-fpm:/var/log/php-fpm:rw'
>
> ERROR: for db  Cannot create container for service db: invalid bind
>   mount spec
>   "C:\magedevbox\shared\var\logs\mysql:/var/log/mysql:rw": invalid
>   volume specification:
>   'C:\magedevbox\shared\var\logs\mysql:/var/log/mysql:rw'
>   [31mERROR[0m: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
>   ERROR: No container found for web_1
>
> Install Magento
>
> [31mERROR[0m: No container found for web_1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: post your issue/question here:  https://github.com/magento/magento2devbox-web/issues

Answer (score 1):

you need to create file .env with following content

COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1 and put that file next to docker-compose.yml

Note : file without name is not possible to make in windows GUI so use command prompt ($ null > .env)